# How do i fix this error ? "linux/linkage.h No such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm doing linux kernel programming. when i add my system call, i got error  "linux/linkage.h No such file or directory". in source.c file, so i move to 
include/linux and check linkage.h using vi. however, linkage.h code is in there. 
why occur this situation?

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>

asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void){
    printk(KREN_EMERG "HelloWorld!\n");
    return 1;
}
```

P.S )

root@kernel-VirtualBox:/usr/src/linux-4.4.1/arch/x86/entry/syscalls# vi syscalls_64.tbl

I added

```
326 64 helloworld sys_helloworld
```

326 is last number of systemcalls

and

root@kernel-VirtualBox:/usr/src/linux-4.4.1/include/linux# vi syscalls.h

in the end of line(#endif above)

```
asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void);
```

and

root@kernel-VirtualBox:/usr/src/linux-4.4.1/kernel# vi Makefile

added helloworld.o at obj-y

```
obj-y     = fork.o exec_domain.o panic.o \
        cpu.o exit.o softirq.o resource.o \
        sysctl.o sysctl_binary.o capability.o ptrace.o user.o \
        signal.o sys.o kmod.o workqueue.o pid.o task_work.o \
        extable.o params.o \
        kthread.o sys_ni.o nsproxy.o \
        notifier.o ksysfs.o cred.o reboot.o \
        async.o range.o smpboot.o helloworld.o
```

and i make helloworld.c at linux-4.4.1/kernel

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>


asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void){

    printk(KERN_EMERG "Helloworld\n");

    return 1;
```

}

and i recomplied kernel, and then, compile helloworld.c, but it appears error linux/linkage.h no such file or directory

Comment: Which kernel's Makefile you have modified for compile your source file? And how you have modified it? Knowing version of the kernel you built would also be helpful.

Comment: @Tsyvarev   my kernel version is 4.4.1, after i modified kernel infomation to make systemcall, i compiled kernel use "make mrproper" and make, however I did not "make modules_install" is it make problem?

Comment: `after i modified kernel infomation to make systemcall` - What **exactly** have you modified? Add this information into your question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev confirm  please

Comment: Yes, this is what I have asked. Addition of the syscall looks correct, at least basically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  so.. what wrong with my code T.T  I'm really want to print HelloWorld T.T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104547/discussion-between-kim-and-tsyvarev).

Comment: how are you compiling helloworld.c ?, for compiling as a kernel module you need to specify the library location or compiler will take default library from /usr/local/lib. So you must create a different makefile to compile it. Google it how to create makefile for kernel module you can find it.